# Changing Section Heading Style Ruins Theorem Counter

Tags: amsthm

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Section \arabic{section}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{}

\begin{theorem}
    A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

**Section 1**
**Theorem Section 1.1.** A theorem.

I would like it to say:

**Section 1**
**Theorem 1.1.** A theorem.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `theorem` counter is dependent on the `section` counter (due to your definition of `theorem`). To that end, `\thetheorem` prints `\thesection.\arabic{theorem}`. So, if you modify `\thesection`, it will end up in the printing of the theorem title. A different approach might be to just update the way the section number is formatted inside the sectioning command(s):

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{Section~\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother
```

This will hold true for all sectioning commands, including `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` (and possibly others). However, this may be sufficient. Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{Section~\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{}

\begin{theorem}
    A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a duplicate of a question you answered to.

Comment: @egreg: It's easy how much one can forget within 1.5 years... :-|